# How can I place two containers next to each other using relative positioning

Tags: html, css

I would like to place two containers next to each other. I want to have as less CSS as possible and therefor inherited most of the CSS to both containers. I moved the second one to the right by overwriting the absolute positioning `left`.

But why does the second container move down as well?

```css
#blopWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 88vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttonDemo, .buttonStart {
  width: 8%;
  height: 6%;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  top: 30%;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #280D83;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.buttonStart {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #230979;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="blopWrapper">

  <div class="buttonDemo">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="buttonStart">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make #blopWrapper display: flex

Comment: remove relative for the button and set it to absolute,so they don't see each others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use display:flex; and specify the flex direction you want using flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;

Also you should attach these CSS properties to a  which contain all of your three divs.

So you should have someting like this:

`#blopWrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}`

and you should remove any style related to the positioning from the children `div`s.

You can find all information about this here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Your `code` should be something like the following:

```css
#blopWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.buttonDemo, .buttonStart {
  width: 8%;
  height: 6%;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  top: 30%;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #280D83;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.buttonStart {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #230979;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="blopWrapper">

  <div class="buttonDemo">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="buttonStart">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set divs as inline blocks, and just align text after that

Like this:

```
.buttonDemo, .buttonStart {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 8%;
    height: 6%;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #CFCFCF;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #280D83;
    border-radius: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
```

Comment: Tried it with the snippet attached. That really doesn't work.

Comment: Try using pixels instead of %, this might help because your divs are creating extra space on right, and that's why it actually go next to each other, use Inspect element and you will get what I'm talking about